# Why cant my google developers console access APIs & auth?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have signed into Google with my Google account and visited http://console.developers.google.com.

There, I created a project and clicked that project.

Then, when I click APIs or Credentials under 'APIs & auth' section, the right pane fades with loading icon, and no content is shown there.

The screenshot is attached here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fyo3ud&s=8#.VA1sFRb4Jbc

What is the reason that my screen halts here?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried it and is doing the same with me!!

Anyway, try this https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect for the old Google API Console version and it will work

**Update:** I just tried it in Firefox and it works fine but still doesn't work in IE!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it in Chrome, and it seems to work well, all the Enabled APIs were showing after I clicked on the APIs under 'APIs & auth' section.

I think one of the reasons for the problem occurred to you is because the project was so new that there would be some halts ?